# How do I prevent DOM libraries from normalizing XML namespaces?

Tags: xml, normalization, transformation, xml-namespaces, jdom

I have an XML document like this:

```xml
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sec="http://namespace1" xmlns:ser="http://namespace2">
    <soap:Header>
        <sec:RequestHeader>
            <sec:SenderId>ABCD</sec:SenderId>
            <sec:SignerId1>ABCD</sec:SignerId1>
            <sec:SignerId2></sec:SignerId2>
            <sec:SignerId3></sec:SignerId3>
            <sec:DBCryptId></sec:DBCryptId>
            <sec:RequestId>CPMDDEV4110066</sec:RequestId>
            <sec:Timestamp>2015-03-24T15:40:00Z</sec:Timestamp>
            <sec:Language>DA</sec:Language>
        </sec:RequestHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ser:GetStatus>
            <ser:dacGetStatusInput>
                <ser:MerchantId>A</ser:MerchantId>
                <ser:OrderId>B</ser:OrderId>
                <ser:CustomerId></ser:CustomerId>
                <ser:ActionCode>C</ser:ActionCode>
                <ser:Test>Y</ser:Test>
            </ser:dacGetStatusInput>
        </ser:GetStatus>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

No matter what I do I cannot get org.w3c.dom nor JDom to stop normalizing namespaces in my source document once I parse it.

If I try to add the top node element to a new document for example, like so:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.newDocument();
document = doc.importNode(document, true);
doc.appendChild(document);
```

I find that if I dump the content of *doc*, the content has changed to:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <sec:RequestHeader xmlns:sec="http://namespace1">
            <sec:SenderId>ABCD</sec:SenderId>
            <sec:SignerId1>ABCD</sec:SignerId1>
            <sec:SignerId2/>
            <sec:SignerId3/>
            <sec:DBCryptId/>
            <sec:RequestId>CPMDDEV4110066</sec:RequestId>
            <sec:Timestamp>2015-03-24T15:40:00Z</sec:Timestamp>
            <sec:Language>DA</sec:Language>
        </sec:RequestHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ser:GetStatus xmlns:ser="http://namespace2">
            <ser:dacGetStatusInput>
                <ser:MerchantId>A</ser:MerchantId>
                <ser:OrderId>B</ser:OrderId>
                <ser:CustomerId/>
                <ser:ActionCode>C</ser:ActionCode>
                <ser:Test>Y</ser:Test>
            </ser:dacGetStatusInput>
        </ser:GetStatus>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The two namespace declarations *sec* and *ser* has been moved to where they are used the first time.
While this normalization is correct, I would like DOM and JDOM to stop doing this and leave my document alone :-)

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I believe you, at least when it comes to JDOM. If I run the following code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build("soap.xml");

    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xout.output(doc, System.out);
}
```

with your document as "soap.xml", I get the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sec="http://namespace1" xmlns:ser="http://namespace2">
  <soap:Header>
    <sec:RequestHeader>
      <sec:SenderId>ABCD</sec:SenderId>
      <sec:SignerId1>ABCD</sec:SignerId1>
      <sec:SignerId2 />
      <sec:SignerId3 />
      <sec:DBCryptId />
      <sec:RequestId>CPMDDEV4110066</sec:RequestId>
      <sec:Timestamp>2015-03-24T15:40:00Z</sec:Timestamp>
      <sec:Language>DA</sec:Language>
    </sec:RequestHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ser:GetStatus>
      <ser:dacGetStatusInput>
        <ser:MerchantId>A</ser:MerchantId>
        <ser:OrderId>B</ser:OrderId>
        <ser:CustomerId />
        <ser:ActionCode>C</ser:ActionCode>
        <ser:Test>Y</ser:Test>
      </ser:dacGetStatusInput>
    </ser:GetStatus>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

which is what I would expect.

JDOM honors the `xmlns` declarations on the element they are declared on, though, if you "move" the elements in to a location where the namespace is not inherited, it will declare it at the point it is needed. Let me explain that better......

```java
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build("soap.xml");
    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xout.output(doc, System.out);
```

The above code simply reads, and dumps the entire document, but, what if we did (read the doc, extract a subset, add the subset to a new doc, and print):

```java
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build("soap.xml");

    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    //xout.output(doc, System.out);

    Namespace soap = Namespace.getNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
    Namespace sec = Namespace.getNamespace("sec", "http://namespace1");

    // locate, and extract rhead
    Element rhead = doc.getRootElement().getChild("Header", soap).getChild("RequestHeader", sec);
    rhead.detach();

    // add it to a new Soap doc.
    Element nroot = new Element("Dummy", soap);
    nroot.addContent(rhead);
    Document ndoc = new Document(nroot);

    // Print the new document
    xout.output(ndoc, System.out);

    //Now force-declare the namespace on the root element:
    nroot.addNamespaceDeclaration(sec);

    System.out.println("\nForced\n");

    xout.output(ndoc, System.out);
```

The above will output the dummy document twice, once with the as-needed declaration with the namespace, the second time with the declaration added to the root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Dummy xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <sec:RequestHeader xmlns:sec="http://namespace1">
    <sec:SenderId>ABCD</sec:SenderId>
    <sec:SignerId1>ABCD</sec:SignerId1>
    <sec:SignerId2 />
    <sec:SignerId3 />
    <sec:DBCryptId />
    <sec:RequestId>CPMDDEV4110066</sec:RequestId>
    <sec:Timestamp>2015-03-24T15:40:00Z</sec:Timestamp>
    <sec:Language>DA</sec:Language>
  </sec:RequestHeader>
</soap:Dummy>

Forced

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Dummy xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sec="http://namespace1">
  <sec:RequestHeader>
    <sec:SenderId>ABCD</sec:SenderId>
    <sec:SignerId1>ABCD</sec:SignerId1>
    <sec:SignerId2 />
    <sec:SignerId3 />
    <sec:DBCryptId />
    <sec:RequestId>CPMDDEV4110066</sec:RequestId>
    <sec:Timestamp>2015-03-24T15:40:00Z</sec:Timestamp>
    <sec:Language>DA</sec:Language>
  </sec:RequestHeader>
</soap:Dummy>
```

JDOM is quite capable of doing what you want.